# node.js localhost https server not working anything

Tags: node.js, https

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
  cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem')
};

https.createServer(options,(req,res)=>{

  console.log('https server start');
}).listen(8080,'localhost');
```

Dear every one,
I tried make https server... and this code.
But not working.

Before i make key.pem, cert.pem for localhost server

Like this code

```
openssl genrsa 1024 > key.pem
openssl req -x509 -new -key key.pem > cert.pem
```

and this thing in the same folder

but not working like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMCPN.png)

Thank you and Regards.!

Comment: Hope this help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60947658/9585130

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "it's not working" image isn't showing any errors, so it seems to start up just fine.

However, the code that handles the request isn't actually sending back a response, which would result in requests just "hanging".

Instead, try this:

```
https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
  res.end('Hello, world!');
}).listen(8080, 'localhost', () => {
  console.log('https server start');
});
```

Comment: Dear robertklep. first thank you for your A~~~~wsome anwer to me i fix it my applications. really really thank you have a good day!